# RPC over HTTPS with Linux Web App

Tags: linux, exchange, https, rpc

I have a PHP/MySQL web application that runs on a Linux server running postfix. I use a phpmailer script which I can configure to relay via IMAP/SSL for accounts with valid login credentials. I have an email account that runs on Exchange server which will not accept normal IMAP connections and requires Outlook or a mail client with the option to configure an Exchange account. I believe it authenticates with RPC over HTTPS. Is there any way to automate relay of email traffic via this account (for which I have valid credentials) via a Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure rpc over https is the only literal option?  Any chance they have EWS or OWA available?  I'm not aware of an RPC-based linux client; even the Mac Outlook client from Microsoft uses EWS, not RPC over https.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was using EWS. There is an application called [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) which functions as an Exchange gateway. This was simple to set up, runs as a service and solved my problem. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-davmail-exchange-gateway-on-a-debian-7-vps) was very helpful.